# return key value pair from object whose key matches certain condition with javascript and underscore

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, underscore.js

```
var obj = {
"M_18-24":413109,
"F_18-24":366159,
"F_25-34":265007,
"U_25-34":1214,
"U_35-44":732
}
```

I want to return an object with key value pairs whose keys start with either "M" or "F".  So the final object would look like

```
var obj = {
"M_18-24":413109,
"F_18-24":366159,
"F_25-34":265007
}
```

I've tried things like _.filter(obj, function(v,k) { return /^[MF]/.test(k) })...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the trick:

```
function filte_obj_FM (inp) 
{
    var ret = {};

    for ( var k in inp) 
    {
        if ( k[0] == "M" || k[0] == "F" ) 
        {
            ret[k] = inp[k];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

see console output (F12 +-> see console) here: http://jsfiddle.net/vH3ym/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
for (var prop in obj) { console.log(prop) }
```

It will give you the corresponding properties, then you can add your logic like

```
if(prop.indexOf('M'))
```

Comment: I think you mean `prop.indexOf('M')`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var obj = {
    "M_18-24":413109,
    "F_18-24":366159,
    "F_25-34":265007,
    "U_25-34":1214,
    "U_35-44":732
} 
var filtered = {}
for(var key in obj) { 
  if(key[0] === "M" || key[0] === "F"){
    filtered[key] = obj[key]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version this time using **reduce**:

// create a new underscore function that will return the properties from an object that pass a given predicate

```
_.mixin({ filterProperties: function(obj, predicate){

    return  _.reduce(obj, function(memo, value, key){

        if( predicate(key) ){
            memo[key] = value;
        }

        return memo;

    }, {});
}});
```

// A couple of predicates that we can use when calling the new function

```
function isMale(key){
    return key[0] == 'M';
}    

function isFemale(key){
    return key[0] == 'F';
}
```

// and finally getting the data we want:

```
var males = _.filterProperties( obj, isMale );
var females = _.filterProperties( obj, isFemale );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
_.filter(_.keys(obj), function(key) {
    return key.match(/U/);
}).forEach(function(kv) {
   delete obj[kv];
});
```

I think all of yours are good and I voted them up. Thanks!

Comment: be aware: this will require http://underscorejs.org/ - which is a pretty neat JS addition.